# HTML form doesn't submit in IE, works fine in Chrome

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, submit

Can you please help me with my form. it doesn't submit in IE. It works fine in Chrome and FF... I have no idea where is the problem :S

Here is the code:

```
<form action="http://www.ceramictiles.com/bahamas/search-results/" method="get">
<h3>Select type:</h3> <select id="selectype" name="typeoftile">
<option value="999">All types of tiles</option>
<option value="220">Bathroom ceramic tiles</option><option value="290">Ceramic tiles for projects</option><option value="210">Ceramics outlet</option><option value="280">Facades ceramic tiles</option><option value="240">Floor ceramic tiles</option><option value="230">Kitchen ceramic tiles</option><option value="270">Outdoor ceramic tiles</option><option value="260">Porcelain tiles</option><option value="250">Wall ceramic tiles</option><option value="120">Indoor clinker</option><option value="150">Industrial clinker</option><option value="110">Outdoor clinker</option><option value="410">Glass mosaic</option><option value="440">Inox mosaic</option><option value="420">Stone mosaic</option><option value="430">Vitro mosaic</option></select><br />

<select id="selectype" name="producertype">
<option value="999"></option>
<option value="99952">Alcalagres</option><option value="999773">Aparici</option><option value="999968">Cinca</option><option value="99921414">e-Ceramica</option><option value="99921412">Ebesa</option><option value="9991089">Emigres</option><option value="99928">Exagres</option><option value="9991192">Goldcer</option><option value="99921411">GresTejo</option><option value="99946">Halcon Ceramicas</option><option value="99988">Inalco</option><option value="999580">Keope</option><option value="999405">Mosavit</option><option value="99921413">Nofer</option><option value="9991548">Revigres</option><option value="9991580">Sanindusa</option><option value="999125">Tau Ceramica</option><option value="999136">Vives</option><option value="999137">Zirconio</option></select>
<i>Categories are covering each other. E.g. Kitchen tiles also contain wall tiles and floor tiles.</i>
<h3>Select size:</h3>

<div style="float:left;padding:12px;"><img src="http://www.ceramictiles.com/bahamas/wp-content/themes/eceramica/images/hor.jpg"><br /><input type='checkbox' name='formatHorizontal' value='1' /></div>
<div style="float:left;padding:12px;"><img src="http://www.ceramictiles.com/bahamas/wp-content/themes/eceramica/images/ver.jpg"><br /><input type='checkbox' name='formatVertical' value='1' /></div>
<div style="float:left;padding:12px;"><img src="http://www.ceramictiles.com/bahamas/wp-content/themes/eceramica/images/squ.jpg"><br /><input type='checkbox' name='formatSquare' value='1' /></div>

<div style="float:left;padding:2px;"><img src="http://www.ceramictiles.com/bahamas/wp-content/themes/eceramica/images/hei.jpg"></div>
<div style="float:left;padding:2px;"><h3 style="display:inline;">></h3><input type='text' name='heightmin' size='1'>cm<br /><h3 style="display:inline;"><</h3><input type='text' name='heightmax' size='1'>cm</div>
<div style="float:left;padding:2px;"><img src="http://www.ceramictiles.com/bahamas/wp-content/themes/eceramica/images/wid.jpg"></div>
<div style="float:left;padding:2px;"><h3 style="display:inline;">></h3><input type='text' name='widthmin' size='1'>cm<br /><h3 style="display:inline;"><</h3><input type='text' name='widthmax' size='1'>cm</div>


<h3>Select color:</h3> <select id="selectype" name="coloroftile">
<option value="900">All colors</option>
<option value="9003">Beige</option><option value="9004">Black</option><option value="9005">Blue</option><option value="9008">Brown</option><option value="90014">Gold</option><option value="90013">Green</option><option value="9001">Grey</option><option value="9006">Orange</option><option value="9009">Pink</option><option value="9007">Red</option><option value="90011">Silver</option><option value="90012">Violet</option><option value="9002">White</option><option value="90010">Yellow</option></select>
<br />
<input class="highlight_input_btn fr" type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

Thanks a lot!

Form is located here: http://www.ceramictiles.com/bahamas/

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ceramictiles.com%2Fbahamas%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: The form submits on IE, too. So does the form than opens up when click on “Search” on top right corner of the page you specified. If you observed something different, you need to specify exactly what you tried on which version of IE and what happened.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ids. IDs must be unique.
Check it out [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/idselector) :

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. You mean the selectype id? I changed that now and it still doesn't submit :( I am using IE 8 at the moment. When I click Find in the popup search box, nothing happens. Thank you all once again for trying to help.

Comment: I have also tried removing the conlist id but that doesn't solve the problem either. Please help if you have any more ideas :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a form that was working in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.

The problem was that the form not submitted was nested into another form.
Bringing the form out from the other solved the problem for me.